# Do Android ad-hoc APK installs get google play market updates?

Tags: android, apk, google-play

Whenever I get a support request on a free version, I respond with a courtesy link to a non-DRM APK of the pro version. Do these ad-hoc APK installs somehow link to the google play market by application ID and know to get updates, or are ad hoc installs frozen in time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paid apps and managed in-app purchases are tied to the user's Google account, so I don't think this should work. However, if you `adb install` a paid app, the Market/Play application displays it as 'installed', so you might get an update notification. Assuming it allows you to actually update, if your published app is using LVL, you should get an licensing error, because the app is not linked with the user's Google account. If not, it might just work. Test it when you upgrade your app to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think at the very least if someone installs from your link they will still be able to get updates from the market. As long as you use the same apk for market and your links.

I think that it will work because if I have a market signed apk and install it with adb, or manually by putting it on the sdcard, or downloading it. Once its installed I am able to go the market to install from there and replace it.

I don't know however if it will get the notification reminders for updates, but I suspect that it would as long as you set the versions in the manifest accordingly.

I also don't know how it would work it if you have in app purchases or some of the other fancy billing things they offer now.